# Ngx-Bootstrap popover not setting correct height or width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, ionic-framework, bootstrap-4, ngx-bootstrap

I am trying to use [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/popover) in my Ionic 2 / Angular 2 app and for some reason the popover is not displaying correctly in my view:

```
<button
  placement="right"
  [outsideClick]="true"
  popover="this is a teseofnwifo ef efo efoih wefohwefo wef  h ioef  whefhweofihwoeht"
  [isOpen]="true"
  triggers="click"

  ion-button full outline 
  class="flex-col rounded box-shadow" 
  color="primary" 
  style="height:100%;font-size:16px;border-width:1px;" 
  (click)="goTo('new-client')" #1>
  <i class="fa fa-user-plus text-shadow" padding style="font-size: 150px;color:red;"></i>
  <span style="font-size:32px;text-transform:none;">New Client</span>
</button>
```

I don't believe my button styling should impact the popover as its rendered as a seperate component, but when the popover is displayed, both its `width` and `height` are set to 4px.  I'm not sure where it's being set or if I'm missing some javascript somewhere..

**app.module.ts**

```
import { PopoverModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/popover';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [
    PopoverModule.forRoot()
  ]
  ...
})
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried with Tooltip ?

Comment: Tooltip spacing works, but I need a popover

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Angular 9. My only way was to force change it globally using ng-deep

```
::ng-deep popover-container {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    background-color: black !important;
    color: white !important;
}

::ng-deep .bs-popover-bottom>.arrow::after {
    border-bottom-color: black !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set container="body", as in demo: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/popover#container-body

If it will fix size then something is affecting popover style

Comment: I still have the same issue even after adding the `container`

Comment: Then need stackblitz sample