# ngx-bootstrap popover display in one line, Text goes beyond the popover

Tags: css, angular, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap-popover

When trying to get a popover displayed in one line using this template:

```
<ng-template #popTemplate>Here we go: <div [innerHtml]="html" class="myClass"></div></ng-template>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success"
      [popover]="popTemplate" popoverTitle="Dynamic html inside">
  Show me popover with html
</button>
```

And by adding a *CSS class* like:

```
myClass {
    white space: nowrap;
}
```

Then the text goes beyond the popup itself.

I've tried to add **container="body"** or **[container]="body"** as in the ngx-bootstrap documentation but it is not working

Is there any proper way to have the popover having all the content text inside it ?

This case happen when the content text is long.

I've looked at this answer:

[Ngx-Bootstrap popover not setting correct height or width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47840797/ngx-bootstrap-popover-not-setting-correct-height-or-width)

But it is not working.

**Update :**

Now, I'm able to see the popover in the debugger, by hovering the tooltip, the following code is added with the pseudo class `::before`

```
<popover-container role="tooltip" style="display: block; top: -6px; left: 310px;" 
    _nghost-c3 class="popover in popover-right bs-popover-right right">
    ...
</popover-container>
```

I don't know from where the value `310px` comes from, but it looks like ngx-bootstrap didn't respond to the provided CSS

Trying an inline CSS directly in the div of the template as:

```
style="display: inline-block; min-width: 100%; white-space: nowrap;"
```

Do not work too.

I found that even when you put an inline CSS, the resulting style is as above in the template as `style="display: block; top: -6px; left: 310px;"` which is very strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finaly I have found the right solution by using this CSS:

```
.popover {
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: none;
}
```

Because we can see at the generated html code for this popover (see the question), that there are 5 classes used, then I used one of them to apply the relevant CSS.

And I've to set `encapsulation` to [`ViewEncapsulation.None`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation) in the popover custom component (which uses an input text, to be displayed)

Comment: i needed to add `::ng-deep .popover` instead of `.popover`

Comment: OK, it might be possible. From my side it was sufficient with ``.popover``

Answer (score 1):

add `max-width: 100%;` to `myClass`

```
.myClass {
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```